# How to define identity based data access in the bicep template

Tags: azure, powershell, claims-based-identity, azure-bicep

I have the below as the bicep template, I want to use the identity based connection, how can I build the template accordingly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference#connecting-to-host-storage-with-an-identity

I used the guidance here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/quickstart-create-bicep-use-visual-studio-code?tabs=PowerShell , for deployment.

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Name exampleRG -Location eastus

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName exampleRG -TemplateFile ./main.bicep -storageName "{your-unique-name}"
```

But, I am getting error while addressing the template file - Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template deployment 'bicepeg' is
not valid according to the validation procedure

```
var baseName = uniqueString('identityRepro', subscription().id)
var location = 'uksouth'

resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: baseName
  location: location 
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}

resource asp 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2019-08-01' = {
  name: baseName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1'
    tier: 'Dynamic'
  }
}

resource ai 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2015-05-01' = {
  name: baseName
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
  }
}

resource fa 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2019-08-01' = {
  name: baseName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: asp.id
  }
  kind: 'functionapp'

  resource appSettings 'config@2018-11-01' = {
    name: 'appsettings'
    properties: {
      'AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName': stg.name
      'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME': 'powershell'
      'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION': '~7'
      'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY': ai.properties.InstrumentationKey
    }
  }
}

resource blobContrib 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(fa.name, stg.name, 'ba92f.........d-a403-e96b0029c9fe')
  properties: {
    principalId: fa.identity.principalId
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', 'ba92f.......-a403-e96b0029c9fe')
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
  scope: stg
}
```

Comment: Did you check the Deployments tab in the resource group? It usually has more detailed errors.

Comment: Validation errors are in Access Log tab, check there.

Comment: I am unable to deploy it from the visual studio code. Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template deployment 'bicepeg' is not valid 
according to the validation procedure.

Comment: It does not matter from where you deploy. In Azure portal, on Activity Log you will se your validation attempt and there could be more detailed error, why validation failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the id of the role. Roles are defined at subscription level, not in resource group. In your code instead resourceId function use subscriptionResourceId.

Update: as you clarified more on github issue, your additional problem was how the name is being constructed. `uniqueString` function generate an pseudo-random string (a hash) based on the seed - the parameters you provide to the function. when you give exactly this same values - you will get this same result.

Below code is working for me

```
var baseName = uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)
var location = 'uksouth'

resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: baseName
  location: location 
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}

resource asp 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2019-08-01' = {
  name: baseName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1'
    tier: 'Dynamic'
  }
}

resource ai 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2015-05-01' = {
  name: baseName
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
  }
}

resource fa 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2019-08-01' = {
  name: baseName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: asp.id
  }
  kind: 'functionapp'

  resource appSettings 'config@2018-11-01' = {
    name: 'appsettings'
    properties: {
      'AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName': stg.name
      'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME': 'powershell'
      'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION': '~7'
      'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY': ai.properties.InstrumentationKey
    }
  }
}

resource blobContrib 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(fa.name, stg.name, 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe')
  properties: {
    principalId: fa.identity.principalId
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe')
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
  scope: stg
}
```

In your code use `resourceGroup().id` as `uniqueString` parameter - as it contains unique guid of your subscription and a resource group name, which has to be unique in the subscription - your hash also should be unique. providing only `subscription().id` will generate same string for all deployments to that subscription and resource group in it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But, I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: I've took your code and I deployed it to a RG - and it went fine. However - are you deploying to a clean resource group or do you have some resources in it?

Comment: I am deploying to a new RG

Comment: see my updated answer, based on the input you provided on github.

Comment: I am not sure about templates, I reached out as a part of a users issue regarding the warning, I will have to find a way to uderstand what is custom role. here the Id im using is the subscription id

Comment: Subscription id will be added automatically by subscriptionResourceId function. The guid you need to provide is the guid of the role - either built in or custom.